# What is the meaning of $\vartriangleleft$ symbol?

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation

I have  some  confusion on this [pdf](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/de/AGR/CommutativeAlgebra/pp289-314.pdf)

It is written that

> Consider  now two  submodules  $N$ and $P$  of $M $.
> Define
>
> $(N:P) =\{a \in A \mid aP \subseteq N\}$
>
> Easy  to check
>
> $(N:P)\vartriangleleft A$

Im not  getting  the  meaning  of $\vartriangleleft$

My question: What  is the meaning of $\vartriangleleft$ symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, $I \vartriangleleft A$ denotes that $I$ is an ideal of the ring $A$. (The symbol is also used for normal subgroups but $A$ is a ring, not a group.)

As with subgroups, there is no consensus whether the case $I = A$ is included or whether the ideal needs to be proper. However, it is more common to allow $I = A$, in my experience. (And there is also $\trianglelefteq$ which unambiguously allows improper ideals.)

In your case, you can check that if $P$ is the zero module, we have $(N : P) = A$, so $I \vartriangleleft A$ must include the case $I = A$ for the author of your text.

Answer (score 0):

Some authors use $N \trianglelefteq G$ for a [normal subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup), and $N \vartriangleleft G$ for a normal subgroup $N \neq G$.

But YMMV, for example the Wiki page linked above introduces $\vartriangleleft$ for arbitrary normal subgroubs, so better check the appendix of the article you are reading.

Comment: Sorry, but $A$ is a ring, so the notation denotes ideals, not normal subgroups.